# Mmdrawercontroller change centerNavController with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mmdrawercontroller

In my Swift app i use code like this to navigate to another ViewController.

```
var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someVC") as! someVC
var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
```

How can i add some animation here? Maybe some of them are already in Mmdrawercontroller?